# How to know a transaction is "confirmed"?

Tags: transaction, iri-legacy-api, javascript, development

I'm building a little IOTA test project with TypeScript + Node.js.

I want to start an action when IOTAs are received on an certain address.

I've tried the `findTransactionObjects` function, but I don't understand the result. It contains an Array of all transactions of this address including pending ones. In the `TransactionObject` I only see properties like `address`, `attachmentTimestamp`, `currentIndex`, `tag`, but no one like `confirmed`.

How can I make sure or validate, that a transaction is confirmed with the iota.lib.js?

```
iota.api.findTransactionObjects({"addresses": ["QZZFKBIQNIBFNZBEU9DLGKHRMOWWGRDAYBKFAXSBWMDXEEAWIRUDDOVSEEFJ9ECH9VWJAFKLHSFAYUHJC"] }, function (error, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call the [GetLatestInclusion](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/#getlatestinclusion) convenience function in `iota.lib.js`.

Under the hood, this will first call [getNodeInfo](https://iota.readme.io/reference#getnodeinfo) to find out the latest solid subtangle milestone hash, and then call [getInclusionStates](https://iota.readme.io/reference#getinclusionstates) to determine if the transaction has been confirmed at that milestone. This might be useful if you use a different API (for a different programming language) that does not include the `GetLatestInclusion` function.

Comment: How will this function be implemented once the coordinator is gone?